# Whats the expected value of the maximum of independent, discrete variables?

Tags: expected-value

I have some indipendent, discrete variables $X_1$ through $X_n$, which don't necessarily share the same (known) probability distributions or possible values. What is the expected value of $\max\left\{X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n\right\}$?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689622/expected-value-of-maximum-of-n-independent-dice-rolls) is related but not quite general enough (though I'm sure this could be adapted).

Also, this question comes from a generalization of what I did to answer [this code golf question](https://codegolf.codidact.com/posts/288885) which is about when all variables are dice rolls, for which I found the closed form $6 - \sum_{i=1}^5\left(\frac i 6\right)^n$ (not finding the question I linked above!) and explained it [this way](https://codegolf.codidact.com/posts/288885/288914#answer-288914) which I *definitely* have no idea how to generalize.

Comment: You must know the individual distributions.

Comment: It is possible to upper bound the expectation, is that okay?

Comment: @AndrewZhang A bound in terms of what?

Comment: Since the OP says the question is motivated by dice, it would seem OK to assume the $X_i$ are subgaussian. @uniquesolution

Comment: @DavidG.Stork they are known, I just wanted to specify that they might not be all the same for every variable (one example I can think of which might be interesting is $X_i$ being a roll of a fair $i$-sided dice)

Comment: by the way, what's the correct name for what I call a probability table, ie something like a table of probabilities and values for example $\frac 1 4 \to 7$; $\frac 3 8 \to -2$; $\frac 1 4 \to 9$; $\frac 1 8 \to 0$

Comment: The correct name is "distribution". btw, a discrete random variable may assume a countable number of values. It may be unbounded. Therefore, even for two discrete random variables,  your question is too general, since there is no reason to assume anything.

Comment: @uniquesolution what do you mean by "unbounded"? I would assume the ability to take the expected value of one of the variables is enough requirements for the ability to take the expected value of the maximum

Comment: @uniquesolution oh okay I thought distribution was only a continuous term, good to know it's not

Answer (score 0):

If $X_i>0$ and $F_i(x)=\Pr(X_i\leq x)$ then $\Pr(\max X_i\leq x)=F_1(x)\ldots F_n(x)$ and $E(\max X_i)=\int_0^{\infty}(1-F_1(x)\ldots F_n(x))dx.$

Comment: what if $X_i$ is not positive? can I just integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: $E(X)=\int_0^{\infty}\Pr(X\geq x)dx$ is valid only is $X\geq 0$.

Comment: right, and what if not? is there no nice formula anymore?